# I have a question depending on the location of 'const' in C++

Tags: c++, reference, constants, rvalue, lvalue

```
int i = 0;
int* lv1 = &(++i); //++i is lvalue
//int* rv1 = &(i++); //i++ is rvalue
const int* &rv1 = &i;
int* const &rv2 = &i;
int* &&rv3 = &i;
const int &rv4 = 5;
int const &rv5 = 5;
```

Why is line 5 not giving an error, but line 4 is an error?

In the case of a reference, I know that the upper const and lower consts are meaningless.
Super const means that the variable itself is const,
Sub-const means that the variable's value is const.
This expression is given in C++ Primer.

Comment: line 4 is a reference to a pointer to a `const int`, so you need an actual variable, you can't initialize it with an rvalue pointer to a non-const `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb about `const` is that it applies to the thing on its left, unless there is nothing there, then it applies to the thing on its right.

On line 4, the `const` applies to the `int` only, so `const int* &rv1 = &i;` is a reference to a non-const pointer to a `const int`.

On line 5, the `const` applies to the `*` only, so `int* const &rv2 = &i;` is a reference to a const pointer to a non-const `int`.